# Lacing a sound effect??

Tags: sound-effects

Just wanted some clarification on a definition that I read in one of my students papers but I cannot seem to find it on the net. Can someone offer mean the definition of "Lacing a sound effect". ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard of it, myself, but I'm hardly as experienced as others on here.  My first thought would be that it's adding sweeteners or texture to a bigger effect, in the same way you'd lace a drug with another drug.

Answer (score 6):

"Lacing" a sound effect could refer to the old method of "lacing up tape" - i.e actually putting it on the machine and feeding it to through the heads to a take up reel... as in the expression "let's lace up those car by's and see what we've got..."

Answer (score 1):

I think Sonsey must be right.

"Lace it up on the dubber and see how it flies"

Maybe it means lacing the coffee of the director right before the screening so they are more receptive to the cut they are about to hear?  Highly illegal but most likely very effective.

Comment: @AzimuthAudio... I'll have to remember that one... might prove beneficial on a project I have coming up! :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no Definition of "Lacing a Sound Effect" in the digital formats. However even in the analogue era, there was no "Lacing a sound effect", It was referred to as "lacing a tape".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of it either but good ideas from the others. When you ask him,  please post back.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of it either but good ideas from the others. When you ask him,  please post back.